# css border changes the div size completely?

Tags: html, css

**EDIT: found a very good link explaining all about border collapse:**

[border collapse explained with examples](http://960development.com/understand-css-margins-collapsing/)

**End of edit. Enjoy :)**

I am failing to understand this...
Why applying a 1px solid black border to my div changes the div's size by a lot?
(without the border I can see a relatively thin line as my back ground color, with the border the רectangle of the background color is much wider, see the pictures)
this pic is without applying the border:
[image: div without the border - see the relatively small background]
and now look at this photo (the only difference is the border...)
[image: div with border, suddenly the background is much bigger!]

can someone explain how the border influences so much on the div size / what is really happening here?!

style:

```
#header {
background-color: yellow;
color: white;
text-align: center;
border: 1px solid black;
}
```

here is a fiddle so you can play around:
    [my fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/JimmyBoy/scqw9uzx/)
Thanks a lot,
Jimmy.

Comment: would adding `display:block` have the same effect as the border?

Comment: Also, please provide a code to see what else is going on

Comment: nope, it already has display:block applied.

Comment: That looks like a padding issue to me. I notice that in the first example padding is 1px and padding is not set on the element in the second example. Maybe the element is inheriting additional padding? It would help if you made a fiddle...

Comment: not a padding issue. you can see i disabled it. i will make a fiddle soon (never did it before - there is always a first time :))

Comment: @JimmyBoy fiddles are extremely helpful, and often you discover the reason for the problem while creating the fiddle ;)

Comment: Here is [your fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bff2a0de/). Your 'problem' happens when you have elements inside the `#header` that have margin. H1 has default margin, if you remove it, than there are no problems. You can also use `#header {overflow: hidden}`, which will make background to fill the content.

Comment: @helloWorld here is my code: [/my fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/JimmyBoy/scqw9uzx) remove the border and see what happen.

Comment: @JimmyBoy OK thanks, I believe I solved your problem now. Please see my answer below

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That's because of [margin collapsing](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/margin_collapsing).

The margin is not part of the element iself, it's the distance between the element and surrounding elements, or between the element and containing borders or paddings.

In the first image the margins of your header element (a `h1` perhaps?) is collapsing outside the div. The margins doesn't affect the size of the div, instead it pushes the surrounding elements away.

When you add a border to the div, then the margins of the header element will push the border away from the header element instead of pushing surrounding elements away. The margins of the header element determine the size of the div.

Comment: sounds good, will verify and accept your answer :) thanks

Comment: the link explains it very well, thanks a lot!

Comment: It is something inside the `#header` (most probably a `h1`) that has a margin. By default its margin is collapsed with `#header`. Adding a border prevents that element from combining its margin with `#header`.

Answer (score 1):

The Header size is same, just the background will not fill the area specified as element margin. Your `h1` has default margin at top and bottom which is not calculated by browser to be filled. In order to force it you can use `overflow: hidden;` on Header, an old trick that covers 99% of famous `clearfix` class (for float fix):

```css
#header {
    background: yellow;
    overflow: hidden;
}
#sidebar {
    float: left;
    width: 30%;
    background: green;
}
#content {
    float: left;
    width: 70%;
    background: lime;
}
```

```html
<div id="header">
    <h1>Header</h1>
</div>
<div id="sidebar">
    <h1>Sidebar</h1>
</div>
<div id="content">
    <h1>Content</h1>
</div>
```

The other way would be to avoid `h1` margin and use padding instead, or fixed height:

```css
#header {
    background: yellow;
}
#sidebar {
    float: left;
    width: 30%;
    background: green;
}
#content {
    float: left;
    width: 70%;
    background: lime;
}
h1 {
    margin: 0;
    padding: .8em 0;
}
```

```html
<div id="header">
    <h1>Header</h1>
</div>
<div id="sidebar">
    <h1>Sidebar</h1>
</div>
<div id="content">
    <h1>Content</h1>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add box-sizing to prevent this from happening. Not every browser supports it though.

```
html {
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
*, *:before, *:after {
  -moz-box-sizing: inherit;
  box-sizing: inherit;
}
```

Comment: This does not explain the issue, but also the question should be improved.

Comment: Sorry, I just read border and div size haha.

Answer (score 0):

```
div {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  border: 1px solid yellow;
}
```

Comment: have a look your code is ok https://jsfiddle.net/10mrnz2z/

Answer (score 0):

The total size of an element is going to be defined by:

> Margin>Border>Padding>Actual element size

Your browser's developer console should allow you to see the value of all of these so try and see which one is changing between those two instances. From the pictures provided it looks like the padding may be changing as you manually adjust the border.

Try manual setting these values:

```
#header{
    border: 1px;
    border-color: black;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
```

Comment: the only thing i see changing is the content size

Comment: @JimmyBoy Try setting the margin and padding to 0 in both situations to make sure.

Answer (score 0):

Perfect example why sometimes using [outline](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/outline) instead of `border` can solve a lot of headache.

> Outlines differ from borders in the following ways:
>
> Outlines do not take up space, they are drawn above the content.

With much respect to all other solutions (which are important to understand), try using the following as an easy fix:

```
outline: 1px solid black;
```

instead of

```
border: 1px solid black;
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kwfzhqom/)

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Set margin on the h1 tag to 0:

```
h1 {
    margin:0;
}
```

I updated your fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/8jm1mxqr/)